# Minecraft: Diagonal Line When running with GeForce Graphics Driver

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, graphics-card

There is a diagonal line in my Minecraft when running with my graphics processor. It appears to be a frame error. One side of the line is not updating as fast as the other line

It is especially obvious when you move which is why its hard to get a screenshot

Is there a fix? (Using GeForce GTX 960M, Updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like [screen tearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing). This is caused by differences in refresh rate of your screen and the game framerate. Try switching v-sync on in the graphics options. This should help synchronize the two. There are some downsides listed on the wiki page, such as input lag, although this will only really affect you when playing competitively. During normal survival game play his won't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing ftb infinity evolved with Intel i7 integrated graphics and a GeForce gtx970m I turned v sync off and it seems to be fixed